# C# Matrix to Android Matrix?

Tags: c#, java, android

I have some code here in C#

```
   //take a world Vector2D and make it a relative Vector2D
    public Vector2D WorldToRelative(Vector2D world)
    {
        Matrix mat = new Matrix();
        PointF[] Vectors = new PointF[1];

        Vectors[0].X = world.X;
        Vectors[0].Y = world.Y;

        mat.Rotate(-m_angle / (float)Math.PI * 180.0f);
        mat.TransformVectors(Vector2Ds);

        return new Vector2D(Vectors[0].X, Vectors[0].Y);
    }
```

The problem is android's Matrix does not seem to have rotate and transform vector.

It has pre and post rotation and mapping vectors.

What could I do to correctly port this code to android?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android has a great `Matrix` class; just use `mMatrix.setRotate()` and `mMatrix.setTranslate()` to do your rotation and translation.  If you need to scale, use `mMatrix.setScale()`.

A lot of Android functions prefix with 'set', so `.rotate()` becomes `.setRotate()`.  It just takes a little getting used to!

Answer (score 0):

rotate, scale, and translate are in http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/Matrix.html. they just return a float[]. you will probably have to put your vectors into a matrix to use the methods. you may need to use that transpose of your matrices depending on how android does things.